# Outlook: Default calendar for meeting request

Tags: imap, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013, meetings, meeting-request

I have Outlook 2013 and it synchronizes two calendars from outlook.com.

Now, I am receiving meetings requests via email from another IMAP account.

How can I choose, which calendar will be the default one for these new meeting events?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems like [you might be out of luck](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/default-calendar-in-outlook-2013/a6926c77-a361-42da-8575-6605057f12a1?page=1&tm=1398950183527).

> Unfortunately, a user created calendar cannot be set as a default
>   calendar in Outlook. By design, Outlook will save the calendar entries
>   to the default calendar in the default PST file.
>
> You can change the default PST file to change the default calendar,
>   but it will still save the entries to the default calendar in that
>   particular PST file.